# Why define directive is not working here?

Tags: c

This is the code I'm trying to run and this is just taking one input and giving me the standard deviation result. Also the 'SIZE' is highlighted as red in GNU nano. I wanna know why, so please help.

This is the code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 
#define SIZE 5  
float std_dev(float a[], int n);
float mean(float a[], int n);

int main(){
    float value[SIZE];
    int i;
    printf("Enter float values\n",SIZE);
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        scanf("%f",&value[i]);
        printf("Std.deviation is %f\n", std_dev(value, SIZE));
    }
}

float std_dev(float a[], int n){
    int i;
    float x, sum=0.0;
    x=mean(a,n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        sum+=(x-a[i])*(x-a[i]);
        return(sqrt(sum/(float)n));
    }
}

float mean(float a[], int n){
    int i;
    float sum=0.0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        sum = sum + a[i];
        return(sum/(float)n);
    }
}
```

Commands I gave for the output are-

> gcc StandardDeviation.c -o compilfile -lm
> ./compilfile

One more thing, I'm using Kali Linux.

I'm trying to get the result as the standard deviation after giving the five float values.

Comment: properly **format* the code. I refuse to read unformatted source

Comment: Nano isn't a proper code editor really, it's more of a quick console-only general text editor to use when nothing better is available, or you just need to do some simple text-editing while in a terminal.

Comment: And even without the proper formatting and indentation, there are some pretty big logical problems that can be clearly seen. If you indent your code it will be even more clear.

Comment: Also, there's almost never a need to use the single-precision `float` for floating point numbers. Use `double` instead. And if you have an expression like division, where one of the value is a floating point value, then the other value will automatically and implicitly be converted to a matching floating point value (so there's no need for the cast in e.g. `sum/(float)n`).

Comment: The functions `mean()` and `std_dev()` contain the `return` statement in the `for` loop. It should be after the `for` loop. The same for the `printf("Std.deviation...")` statement in `main()`. The loops are not executed completely. Only the first iteration is executed then the `return` statements force the functions to return. Consequently the results are incorrect. There is nothing wrong with `SIZE` (neither with its definition, nor with its usage).

Comment: Do not ignore the warnings reported by the compiler. Many times they reveal errors in the code logic. Try to understand their cause and repair the code.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to fix the missing formatting.

Comment: Please note that [it is expected that you put an effort into formatting your code before posting a question on Stack Overflow](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/). Also, formatting the code will also make the code more readable for you.

Comment: What is the `SIZE` macro doing here: `printf("Enter float values\n",SIZE);`? You have no format directive to print it. If that's the one in red, that's the reason.

Comment: You shouldn't call `std_dev()` until after you've read in all the numbers. Or if you want to call it incrementally, the second argument should be `i+1`, not `SIZE`, since you don't have `SIZE` numbers until the last iteration.

Comment: @0___________ I'm new in stackoverflow.com. I will search about the right way of asking the question in this platform but still it will help if you can tell me what I did wrong here. Thank You!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually I'm new, not in the C language but also in Kali Linux. I wanted to learn kali linux, I thought I should do the basic programming (that is in my college syllabus) in kali so that I can practice it more. Can you tell me the best alternative of Nano. Also I will try adding division expression to get rid of casting float. Thank You!

Comment: @axiac You're right! I don't know how I did this mistake but I should not return it in the loop otherwise it will return every single time. I apologize for doing this and thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I will read it and do it properly from now on! Thank You!

Comment: `printf("Enter float values\n",SIZE)` should probably be `printf("Enter %d float values\n",SIZE)`.

Comment: Visual Studio Code seems like a popular alternative these days. The C and C++ plugin have [good documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes! I'm using VS Code now! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I did the basic mistake here that I was using return statement inside the loop. It should be something like this:

```
float std_dev(float a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    float x, sum = 0.0;
    x = mean(a, n);
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += (x - a[i]) * (x - a[i]);
    }
    
    return sqrt(sum / (float)n);
}
```

in every function I created here. Thank you for this solution @axiac.
Few more points:

1. I am using Visual Studio Code now.
2. I am learning how to format the code and ask question properly in this platform.
3. I implemented all the suggestions you guys gave me. Thank you!